# Reversing a linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

when reversing the list I am using the following code but it is adding the last element twice.

```
public void reverse()
    {
        Node current,previous,next;
        current=head;
        previous=null;
        while(current!=null)
        {
            next=current.getNext();
            current.setNext(previous);
            previous=current;
            current=next;
        }
        head=previous;
    }
```

The node class is following

```
public class Node 
{
    private Node next;
    private String data;

    public Node(String dataValue) {
        next = null;
        data = dataValue;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I am adding the data in the list by following

```
public void add(String data)
    {
        if(head==null)
        {
            head=new Node(data);
        }
        Node temp=new Node(data);
        Node current=head;
        if(current!=null)
        {
            while(current.getNext()!=null)
            {
                current=current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(temp);
        }
    }
```

After reversing the list the output I am getting is following

Original list : [1][2][3][4][5]
Reversed List : [4][3][2][1][1]

Comment: Examples like this are best understood if you make a little drawing and move pointers as assignments are made in the program. You will soon recognize where it goes wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `java.util.List` ?

Comment: just add the return statement to your add method when the head node is null.

Comment: it's also missing the last element `[5]`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the `add` method when there is `no head` so far, you need to add a `return` statement to avoid adding itself as `next node`, as next:

```
public void add(String data)
{
    if(head==null)
    {
        head=new Node(data);
        // Exit of the method to prevent adding the head as next element
        // of the head
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

With this simple change if I do:

```
// Create the list
MyList list =  new MyList();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
list.add("5");

// Print the list content
current = list.head;
while(current != null){
    System.out.println(current.getData());
    current = current.getNext();
}

// Inverse the list
list.reverse();
System.out.println("****");
// Print again the list content
current = list.head;
while(current != null){
    System.out.println(current.getData());
    current = current.getNext();
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
****
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

When filling your list the head is set to [1] and afterwards you insert a node [1] behind this head.
So you always have the first element of your list twice.

You'd better use `java.list.LinkedList` which you can fill with `Node`

```
 List<Node> yourList = new LinkedList<Node>();
 yourList.add(new Node(1));
 yourList.add(new Node(2));
```

You can then reverse your list by simply running:

```
Collections.reverse(yourList);
```

Comment: The question is obviously a programming excercise, I very much doubt that this will qualify as a solution.